# How to create charts using NodeJS server side programming

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a database file in json which contains WiFi data. I want to populate that data in a graphical format on browser. Can anyone please suggest how to do it or what steps I should follow. I am very new to programming and not aware of nodejs. I have already done this in javascript clint side, however for server side programming any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can anyone please help with a suggestion on this topic

Answer (score 0):

Looks like using chart-js on the server side (with jsdom and canvas) is the way to do it.

See:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-node
- http://blog.stevenedouard.com/how-to-render-chart-js-charts-serverside/